# Why does it say "C is the greatest" when nothing is given as input?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Greatest of three</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter A"));
            var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"));
            var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter C"));

            if(a == b && b == c)
                document.write("A , B and C are equal! Give distinct numbers.")
            else if(a == b)
                document.write("A and B are equal! Give distinct numbers.");
            else if(b == c)
                document.write("B and C are equal! Give distinct numbers.");
            else if(c == a)
                document.write("A and C are equal! Give distinct numbers.");
            else if(a > b) {
                if(a > c)
                    document.write("A is the greatest");
                else
                    document.write("B is the greatest");
            }
            else {
                if(b > c)
                    document.write("B is the greatest");
                else
                    document.write("C is the greatest");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does it say that "C is the greatest" when nothing is given as input? 
And if I have to break it when NULL is given, how would I do it?

Comment: Assuming a and b are different values and b > a, 'C is the greatest' is displayed because that's what your logic tells it to do.

Comment: Because it converts null input to NaN? Comparing NaN and NaN gives no equal.

Comment: In addition to what everybody else has said, you should never call `parseInt()` without a radix argument, as it's a common source of bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If nothing is entered, this line of code

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter A"));
```

will return a value of `NaN` for `a` (and the other variables).

As neither `NaN == NaN` nor `NaN < NaN` results in `true`, all your `if`-statements will resolve to the else block, which in the end yields `document.write("C is the greatest");`.

To check for this use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) like this:

```
if ( isNaN( a ) ) {
  // some code to handle this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't provide anything to prompt; then `a = parseInt(prompt("Enter A"))` makes `a = NaN` (NaN means Not A Number).  Then the conditions fail; `NaN < NaN` is false as is `NaN == NaN`.  Basically any comparison where one side is NaN will always be false.  Going through your logic, that will print "C is the greatest"

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(b>c)
        document.write("B is the greatest");
    else 
        document.write("C is the greatest");
```

Here In the whole logic, you are just checking `a>b`, `a>c` ... but you are not checking for `NaN`, To check the value is `NaN`, use `isNaN()`

Comment: @DanielVictor: I mean that you have to check for `isNaN()`

Answer (score 0):

In trinary logic, relations involving Null always return false.  Even comparisons between two Null values.  NaN values in Javascript follow these rules.

Therefore the `else` path is always taken.

Comment: It's not `null`, it's `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Because this gets triggered.

```
else
{
    if(b>c)
        document.write("B is the greatest");
    else 
        document.write("C is the greatest");
}
```

And if there's no input `b` would == `c` so therefore the final `else` (C is the greatest) gets triggered.

You need to check that you have input. You could this by wrapping an extra block around the whole thing:

```
if( a && b && c ) {
   // your if statements
}
else {
   alert("No input!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Becaus a = NaN

Compare NaN == NaN is false!

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter A"));
        var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"));
        var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter C"));
        document.write(a);// << os NaN
        document.write(a == b); //<< Is False!!
    if(a==b && b==c)
        document.write("A , B and C are equal! Give distinct numbers.") 
    else if(a==b)
        document.write("A and B are equal! Give distinct numbers.");
    else if(b==c)
        document.write("B and C are equal! Give distinct numbers.");
    else if(c==a)
        document.write("A and C are equal! Give distinct numbers.");

    else if(a>b)
    {
        if(a>c)
            document.write("A is the greatest");
        else
            document.write("B is the greatest");
    }
    else
    {
        if(b>c)
            document.write("B is the greatest");
        else 
            document.write("C is the greatest");
    }   
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How do I break it or alert when they user gives NaN?